# Concise Way to Structure Multi-Variable Data in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data with 3 independent variables that I need to perform calculations with and display in a presentable way. Here's an example of what the data looks like:

[image: Table 1]

Obviously this structure isn't usable for calculations between X and Y, W and Z, etc. So I laid out a table like this:

[image: Table 2]

This is super easy to work with; performing calculations between X and Y as well as filtering data by variables works well. I need to find a more presentable way to display the data however. I've been told to make something that looks like this:

[image: Table 3]

It looks nice, but I think it's going to be difficult to look up values with the merged cells. I'm just looking for advice on how to structure this sort of data in a usable way.

Comment: Keep the data in a form that is easy to use and use a new sheet that "presents" that data in the way desired, but is tied to the data table.